# Finding polynomials for given sets of roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

Lets consider polynomials of degree 4, with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ and the ratios of their roots being roots of unity. Moreover, let those roots to be distinct. Now, consider the following given lists of roots:
$$r^{1/4}(1,i,-1,-i), \quad
r^{1/2}(\omega^2, -\omega^2,\omega,-\omega), \quad
r(\epsilon, \epsilon^2, \epsilon^3, \epsilon^4), \quad
r \sqrt2 (\xi \omega, \xi \omega^2, \xi^{-1}\omega, \xi^{-1}\omega^2)$$
where $\epsilon = exp(2 \pi i/5), \omega=exp(2 \pi i/3), \xi=exp(\pi i /4)$ and $r \in \mathbb{Q}$.

My question now is, how i can find all those polynomials, whose roots are listed above?

**My idea:**

Lets take the second one for example. So let $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a polynomial of degree 4 and its roots are
$r^{1/2}(\omega^2, -\omega^2,\omega,-\omega)$. If we know the roots of $p$, we also know its factors, i.e.
$$p(x) = (x - r^{1/2}\omega^2)(x + r^{1/2}\omega^2)(x - r^{1/2}\omega)(x + r^{1/2}\omega).$$
Multiplying this out, we get
$$p(x) = (r \omega^2 - x^2)(r \omega^4 - x^2) = x^4 - r \omega^2 (1 + w^2)x^2 + r^2 \omega^6.$$
As in the comment below noted, applying $\omega^3=1, 1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ leaves us with $- r \omega^2 (1 + (-1-\omega)) =  r \omega^3 = r$ for thequadratic coefficient. So finally we get
$$p(x) = x^4 + r x^2 + r^2.$$

Comment: In your case use the relations for roots of unity to simplify, for e.g. $\omega^3=1, 1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ will help.   Also for an alternate approach, you could use Vieta, then the odd power terms vanish, the constant term is obvious and only the quadratic coefficient needs to be calculated (which isn't too difficult).

Comment: Thank you very much! Also that alternate approach via Vieta´s formula works very well.

Comment: @user12345 $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ are the roots of $\,z^4 - 1\,$, so $\,\{\pm \sqrt[4]{r}, \pm i \sqrt[4]{r}\}\,$ are the roots of $\,z^4 - r\,$. $\,\{\pm\omega, \pm\omega^2\}\,$ are the roots of $\,\frac{z^6-1}{z^2-1}=z^4+z^2+1\,$, so $\dots$